# Combine obs with various filter options

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I have the following scenario

Load data if ain't loaded yet

```
 this.mailFacade.mailLoaded$
     .pipe(
       filter(res => !res),
       takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)
      )
     .subscribe(_ => this.mailFacade.get());

    this.userFacade.friendsLoaded$
    .pipe(
      filter(res => !res),
      takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)
    )
    .subscribe(_ => this.userFacade.getFriends());

    this.onlineFacade.loaded$
    .pipe(
      filter(res => !res),
      takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)
    )
    .subscribe(_ => this.onlineFacade.get());
```

I tried to combine all with this

```
    forkJoin([
      this.mailFacade.mailLoaded$,
      this.userFacade.friendsLoaded$,
      this.onlineFacade.loaded$
    ]).pipe(
      filter(([mail, user, online]) => !mail || !user || !online),
      takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)
    )
    .subscribe(([mail, user, online]) => {
      if (!mail) { this.mailFacade.get(); }
      if (!user) { this.userFacade.getFriends(); }
      if (!online) { this.onlineFacade.get(); }
    });
```

I wonder if it is the same, which will be the best implementation for this case?

i want to combine the loaded state but only filter for the data that ain't loaded yet

get() puts the state loaded to **true**

Comment: I actually prefer using the first approach as you have one subscription per "sideeffect". I understand your point but you wont get a "this is the best approach answer". If you stick to reactive programming (for what rxjs is suitable for) your first approach is completely fine.

Answer (score 0):

if I have understood your question, you want to know which of the two methods is the best. This depends on your expectations. In the first snippet of code, what happens is that if a data was already loaded, you don't have to load it again. In case you only have only one data to load, this is the best choice in terms of performance, but not in the other cases. This is because in the first case datas are loaded sequentially, this means that every call must wait the previous one to end. In the second case, otherwise, calls are performed concurrently.
Your choice!

Comment: i mean, i want to use .subscribe() once